# create .elf file using Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have written a Makefile with .bin as my target. The binary file is created from the .elf file. The project contains .c and .cc files. It looks like the .bin file is not created properly. A printf statement was included in the .c file to check the Makefile. Nothing is being printed on the serial monitor. Could someone point out where I am going wrong.

```
$(CONFIG)/%.a: $(LIBS) $(OBJS)
   @echo "Archiving" ;\
   $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $< 

${CONFIG}/%.elf: $(LIBS) $(OBJS)
   ${CC} -T ${LINKER_FILE} ${LFLAGS} -o ${@} $(call 
       fixpath,$(filter %.o, ${^})) $(call fixpath,$(filter %.a, ${^})) 
       ${PROJ_LIBS} ${STD_LIBS}                                                            

$(CONFIG)/$(TARGET).bin: $(CONFIG)/%.elf
   @echo " Copying $(COMPILERNAME) $@..." ;\
   $(CP) $(CPFLAGS) $< $@ ;\
   $(OD) $(ODFLAGS) $< > $(CONFIG)/$(TARGET).lst

clean:
   @echo "Cleaning..." ;\
   $(RM) -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(CONFIG)/$(TARGET).bin $(CONFIG)/%.a ;\          
   $(CONFIG)/%.elf $(CONFIG)/$(TARGET).lst
```

Comment: This is too much code.  Please help us help you by spending some time to prepare a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As for `printf` calls, though, it's not clear what you're expecting. Normally, the code being compiled is not also run as part of the build process, so `printf` calls in the sources being compiled do not produce terminal output during the build.

Comment: I am using the Sparkfun RedBoard(Artemis) for my project. I have used the SDK provided by them that will display a specific output on the serial monitor after the binary file is flashed. Initially my project contained only c files and it was a success. I did a few changes to accommodate the c++ files and no output is displayed on the serial monitor.

Comment: I think the issue is with .elf file. But I am not sure what the exact error is. The only warning I get is this                                                                                  `/home/yasaswini/Desktop/Edge/gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol Reset_Handler; defaulting to 000000000000c000`

Comment: It's suspicious that you are using the C compiler driver to perform the link in a mixed C / C++ project.  One would normally use the C++ compiler driver.  But the combination of C++ and "cannot find entry symbol" makes me suspect that name mangling is playing a part.

Comment: Thank you @John. I edited the Makefile and was able to clear the warning. The warning can also appear if source file with the main is not included in the Makefile.                                                                     
`${CONFIG}/$(TARGET).elf:$(OBJS) $(LIBS)
        @echo " Linking $(COMPILERNAME) $@" ;\
 $(CC) -Wl,-T,$(LINKER_FILE) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS)`

Comment: @Jasmine did you find the answer?  You're using ARM Embedded GNU for compiling, not standard GCC.  The warning you received about `Reset_Handler` means your linker script defines the entry point symbol as `Reset_Handler` but there are no files being compiled in the project that define `Reset_Handler`.  In embedded world, `Reset_Handler` is usually defined in a `.s` file that is provided with an SDK/toolchain.  You shouldn't edit out the entry point in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to be consistent with `${}` vs `$()` for readability purposes.

You should be able to create the `.bin` file using `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` with ease:

```
$(CONFIG)/$(TARGET).bin: $(CONFIG)/%.elf
    $(info Preparing: $@)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@
```

Assuming `$(OD)` is replaced with the name of your `objdump` tool, you may need to replace `$(OBJCOPY)` with `$(OC)` or similar.

Comment: The title is misleading, but I still posted an answer in case someone came upon this.  OP's issue is more likely the Makefile and assembling/compile/linking issues. `Reset_Handler` must exist, and its usually provided as part of a chip/platform package file, probably found in an `.s` file.  If that is not defined, then the chip will not boot to main.